# Is there any ML solutions for permutations?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

In Machine Learning field, is there any work done, or research, or info in general **about finding optimal permutations**?

For eg. to find a number of optimal arrangements of sliced shapes on 2D sheet of material - so that there is low number of leftovers?

I assume it can be done by brute-forcing permutations, but what about neural networks or Machine Learning in general?

Comment: There probably are, but where are you going to find the dataset to train your model? That problem can be formulated as a convex optimization problem. Check out the book by [Boyd and Vandenberghe](http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/)